Unable to delete, crate or modify Event Subscription in Azure IoT Hub
I tried to create an event subscription for Azure Event Grid Namespace. I am a bit new to Azure so I messed up and chose a storage queue as an endpoint as at that time I did not know how to create an event gris system topic and namespace.
Then I deleted that queue without removing the event subscription in IoT Hub. Now after doing some research, I got to know how to create a namespace and system topic and link it with IoT Hub. But maybe due to the above mess-up, I am unable to do any operation on Event Subscription. It's through errors such as below when deleting.
Deletion Error Image:

If I try to change the below message is pops up.
Creation Error Image:

Another one I tried is creating a new event grid namespace and switching the event subscription endpoint from storage queue to Azure Event grid namespace endpoint system topic but during creation time I created Azure Event Subscription with Event Grid Schema now I am unable to change it.
How to solve this issue please enlighten me and really sorry if I was unable to explain properly. Any information I can provide no issues.

which end point you are connecting in  Event Subscription, Please the   ENDPOINT DETAILS

if you use a storage queue create Azure storage and queue. go Events in IoT hub. select Event Subscription. Name as a unique name, select the Name you want, choose the Endpoint Type as Storage Queue, Configure an endpoint by selecting the storage name and queue details, and choose Managed identity type as none.

please share error in text

@error The "failed to disable publisher notifications” error is hiding a 500 error (object not set to an instance of an object) inside the Azure api. This looks like an Azure bug to me as it makes it impossible to create more than 1 event unless you wait a few minutes. Only one operation can be performed for the same resource at a time. Please make sure you are having the resource dependency using Dependson.

with Event Grid Namespace Topic as Endpoint Type

@Sampath Thank you for the response I am really sorry for not being available and replying this late. I was able to understand how to link the event grid to IoT Hub but before I knew it I did a mistake of deleting the endpoint without deleting the event subscription. Due to this I am unable to delete or modify the event subscription I think.

Not yet. I have posted the same in Microsoft as well. I am trying that way as well.

Refer to this link about Error generated with code: 500 and message: Failed to disable publisher notifications.
Below are the steps to route events from Azure IoT Hub to an Azure Storage Queue using Event Subscription:

Create an Azure Storage Account and a queue.

Navigate to your Azure IoT Hub instance and select "Event Subscription" to create a new subscription by giving a unique name for the subscription.

Select the types of events you want to route and choose "Storage Queue" as the endpoint type.

Provide details about the Azure Storage Account and Queue that you created earlier.

Choose whether to use a managed identity or not. If you select "None," it means you'll need to manage access to the storage account manually and save it.



Below are the steps to route events from Azure IoT Hub to an Event Grid Namespace Topic using Event Subscription:

Create an Event Grid Namespace and Topic.

Navigate to Identity in the Event Grid Namespace and enable System assigned.

Navigate to Access control and click on Add role assignment.

Add EventGrid Data Sender to the Topic/Event Grid Namespace Topic with (principal) ID.




Navigate to the Event Subscription of Azure IoT and create an Event Subscription with Event Grid Namespace Topic as Endpoint by selecting the above event grid that was created.

Managed identity type can be system-assigned/User-assigned. I used the system assigned.





Sampath, I am trying the said above but unable to create the Event Subscription in IoT Hub. its throwing as error as below.
Deployment has failed with error: {"code":"Managed Identity Authorization Error","message":"Managed Identity for 6...f91c0:eztriothubsubscription does not have permission to perform Microsoft.EventGrid/events/send/action action on the destination resource /subscriptions/6..6/resourceGroups/rg-eventgrid/providers/Microsoft.EventGrid/namespaces/eztrnamespace/topics/eztriothubtopic. Please grant appropriate permission before creating the event subscription. Any Idea?

Have you added EventGrid Data Sender to the Topic/Event Grid Namespace Topic with (principal) ID.

Adding Event Grid Namespace access is with the owner unfortunately so I can't exactly confirm the principal ID thing but yes, we added Event grid Data Sender Role for it. Is there any other way except using principle ID or is there any way of verifying it?

you can check with the Event grid topic name.

I have just asked with the owner. He conveyed that he is using managed identity.

Hi Sampath, I have added the sender role to namespace successfully but no success. Just for confirmation, Is it to Namespace or Namespace topic? When I try searching for my topic in members I couldn't find it.

Hi Sampath. It seems I need to log out and login after assignment. It worked today which did not worked the day before. Thanks a lot for the support.
